# How do you show validation result in messagebox when calling ValidationResult method?

Tags: c#, validation

I have a method shown below that checks if the passed registration is valid in a list of registrations, where if the if statement returns true, the registration exists.

I am using the method below that returns a validation result depending on whether the conditions are met. What I would like to do is show these results in a textbox when the method is called. How might I achieve this?

```
public static ValidationResult IsValidRegistration(string registration)
{
    try
    {
        if (!Business.VehicleList.Any(x => x.Registration == registration))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(true, $"Vehicle created successfully");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return new ValidationResult(false, $"Registration: {registration} already exists");
    }
    return new ValidationResult(false, $"Failed");
}
```

What Id like to achieve:

```
if (Validation.IsValidVehicle(registration).IsValid)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Success Message");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error Message");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to use a variable to refer to the result, then check the `IsValid` property and fetch the message by accessing the property `ErrorContent` as a string.

```cs
var result = Validation.IsValidVehicle(registration);
var message = result.ErrorContent as string;
if (result.IsValid)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Success Message" + message);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error Message" + message);
}
```

More information about [ValidationResult Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.validationresult?view=net-5.0).

Update:
Based on your comment, you should return the error message if the value of `registration` exists.

```cs
public static ValidationResult IsValidRegistration(string registration)
{
    try
    {
        if (!Business.VehicleList.Any(x => x.Registration == registration))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(true, $"Vehicle created successfully");
        }
        return new ValidationResult(false, $"Registration: {registration} already exists");
    }
    catch
    {
        return new ValidationResult(false, $"Failed");
    }
    return new ValidationResult(false, $"Failed");
}
```

Comment: the issue Im facing though is that it is only returning error no matter what the error is because of the last error message return statement. How do I get it to do`return new ValidationResult(false, $"Registration: {registration} already exists");`

Comment: @MarkHunt I've updated my answer, check it out, please.